# AC adapter interfering with WS2812B LED strip

Tags: noise, ac-dc, ws2812b

[image]

I have 2 power adaptors connected on same AC line, both grounded.

Power adapter 1:

12V DC 10 A for powering 12 V LED strips, controlled by ESP8266, IRLZ44N MOSFET used to control brightness of the LED strips. This works fine without any issue.

Power adapter 2:

5 V DC 5 A for powering 5 V WS2812b LED strip, controlled by ESP8266. This is giving problems. There is random flicker on all LED lights.

**The LED strip is at a distance of 5 feet from ESP8266.**

- Tried using a single LED pixel soon after the controller, but that didn't help.
- Tried using 100 uF caps between power close to LED strip.
- Tried using 100 uF cap on ESP power.
- Tried using 220 Ω resistor in series on data line close to LED strip.

I am now using SP901E signal booster, but the issue persists.

**Few observations:**

- AC power adaptor 1 gives a whining noise when the LED brightness is reduced, If a turn off this adaptor, or set brightness to 0, the flicker is gone instantly. Tried replacing with another adapter, same results.
- If I measure for frequency (using multimeter) between VCC and DIN on WS2812B strip, *the flicker is gone too* (power adapter 1 still powered on)

The voltage is around 5.5 V on the LED strip, which I think is not an issue here, as the flicker goes away in the above 2 scenarios.

How and why is the other AC adapter generating noise on the esp controller which is connected to a different power source?

How does measuring for frequency on a multimeter on solve the flicker issue.(getting frequency - 113-120 kHz)

Thanks :)

Comment: Have You connected both low voltage grounds?

Comment: @fifi_22 no, the 2 AC power supplies are isolated. should i still connect grounds ?

Comment: Have you connected ESP32 digital 3.3V data output pin to 5V LED data input pin?

Comment: @Justme, yes, D4(3.3v) and power go in SP901E signal booster(not in the diagram) and connect to ws2812 strip

Comment: @m4X OK, if the diagram isn't accurate, we don't know what's accurate and what's not. We also don't know what a SP901E signal booster is and what it does, unless the thing has a readable schematic.

Comment: Probably XY problem. Please hook up your oscilloscope to Vcc and data pin of the WS2812B.

Comment: If You connect any data wire from one "thing" to another, grounds also have to bo connected

Comment: Why do you think the other AC adapter is the problem? As drawn they're disconnected circuits, so they should not matter to one another. Or is there a connection between them not in the diagram?

Comment: @user1850479, they are disconnected circuits. Only connected on same AC line.
As mentioned, if if set the 12v led brightness to 0 on adapter 1, the flicker is gone on adapter 2. which seems to be strange. unless the AC adapters are interfering with each other.

Comment: What's the interference mentioned in the title then?

Comment: @fifi_22, my DC circuits are isolated. there is no connection between any the DC components

Comment: @user1850479, interference thats causing random flickers.

Comment: Highly unlikely to be power supply related. Probe the data (and Vcc) pins and check.

Comment: Sorry, missed the bit about unplugging above. Since there's no electrical connection, it's probably not actually interference and just a problem with your wiring. First thing is check is that you have a good ground connection.

Comment: WS2812B flickering is in most cases caused by software. The protocol is timing sensitive. If the CPU cannot transmit the color values for all LEDS with the required timing, flickering occurs because the LEDs at the begging of the strip temporarily show colors that LEDs further down the strip should have shown. To verify it, use the simplest possible firmware (without an remote control features). If the flickering disappears, it's a software problem.